# Missing features after joining by attribute, but geometry is valid

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I've tried joining two point layers by location on QGIS 2.18.27 (Mac iOS 10.13.5 High Sierra), but some points in the new vector don't end up appearing. One point layer is an interpolated point layer of a line, with one point every 500 meters (we'll call this `interpolated_point` layer), and the other point layer is a point at every node of above-mentioned line layer (we'll call this the `node_point` layer), both set to `World Mercator [EPSG:54004]`.

[image: Points and attribute table for <code>node_point</code>layer]
*Points and attribute table for the `node_point` layer*

[image: Points and attribute table for the <code>interpolated_point</code> layer]
*Points and attribute table for the `interpolated_point` layer*

[image: New joined layer]
*The `node_point` layer (left) and the new joined layer (right, using the `Join attributes by location` tool) with missing feature highlighted*

I used the `Join attributes by location` tool in the `Vector > Data management tools` menu and set the `node_point` as the `Target layer` and the `interpolated_point` layer as the `Join vector layer`. The `Geometric predicate` is `within` and `Precision` is set to `500 m` (so that if a point on the `interpolated_point` layer isn't within another point in the `node_point` layer, it'll try to get the attributes of the point within 500 meters; that is, that's how I *think* it works).

[image: Dialogue box]
*`Join attributes by location` dialogue box with entered parameters. `points_mercator` is `node_point` and `interPoints_mercator` is `interpolated_point`*

I've tried checking the [validity of the `node_point` layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253333/join-attribute-by-location-result-lacks-some-features-in-qgis-2-18) and all the features `node_point` layer are all right, so I'm not sure what I'm doing. Reversing the `Target` and `Join vector layer` parameters don't change the (undesired) result either. Any thoughts? The expected result is that I have a new layer that has ***all*** and ***only*** the points from the `node_point` layer with the attribute tables combined by location.

Again, using QGIS 2.18.27 on a Mac iOS 10.13.5 High Sierra.

***EDITS:***

1. Added screenshot of `interpolated_point` and `node_point` layers and their attribute tables (as suggested by @pdavis)
2. Added screenshot of `Join attributes by location`dialogue box with parameters used (as suggested by @pdavis)
3. Added expected results (as suggested by @pdavis)
4. Added `CRS` used

Comment: Do you get your expected result if you switch the target and join layers? I'm assuming there are more points in your interpolated layer than your nodes layer and that's why you're not seeing all your points?

Comment: @pdavis nah, still don’t get the same results. Yes, there are more points in the interpolated layer than the nodes layer, but they’re all on the same line and nearly on top of each other, so I can’t think of why it can’t do at least a proximity join...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some screenshots - images of the layers in the map, the attributes tables, the 'Join by location' dialog box with your filled in parameters, etc. and even possibly what you expect the output table to look like?

Comment: I have included edits @pdavis, hopefully the question is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting edits to help clarify.
There are two things wrong here:

1. You are not correctly understanding the 'within' predicate. This means that one geometry is fully contained within another geometry so using it with points doesn't make sense. The second answer in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/documentation-join-attributes-by-location-qgis-2-18) offers a succint explanation on geometric predicates. My guess as to why you are getting any returns at all is because you have so many points along the line, that one will fall 'within' your node points based on some default precision threshold used by the tool. But I don't know for sure . . .
2. Apparently, the precision parameter in QGIS 2.x didn't work and has been removed for 3.x. See this post: [Join Attributes by Location - Precision](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268992/join-attributes-by-location-precision)

Your operation is a fairly standard analysis and the best way that I've found to accomplish what you want (in QGIS) is to use the [NNJoin plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/). Why QGIS doesn't have native tool to do this I can't understand. Maybe other readers of this post can elaborate.