# QGIS Missing Features on Map

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, features, display

I have a shapefile in QGIS 3.16 that I created by performing a spatial join.  It displayed properly on the map. I then edited some of the data in one of the spatially joined fields. After doing so, some of the features don't show up on the map. It seems random, though. Some unedited ones are visible, some are not. And vice versa.

I've searched online for an answer and have not found anything. Might it have to do with my spatial joins layers not having a spatial index? Or I also noticed the spatial join layer did not have a CRS.

I'm lost.

Comment: Please provide more details on your workflow and maybe exemplary data.

Comment: Also might be helpful to see a few screenshots. For example. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321432/missing-features-after-joining-by-attribute-but-geometry-is-valid

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works